# Gearman on multiple servers in the Cloud

Tags: php, gearman

I've installed Gearman, when running on one server everything is going fine. Now I have three servers, on one I want to run my Client, on one the Worker and another working as the Server.

When I run it locally on one server (without specifying the ip) it runs beautifully. Once it goes external, not so much.

What am I doing wrong in these pieces of code?

Client (running on one server)

```
    $this->client = new GearmanClient();
    $this->client->addServer('51.15.234.178', 4730);
```

Worker (running on another)

```
    $this->worker = new GearmanWorker();
    $this->worker->addServer('51.15.234.178', 4730);
```

The port is open on 51.15.234.178

Thanks so much

Comment: could you connect 51.15.234.178 4730 from client's/worker's environment? Test it with `nc -w 2 -v 51.15.234.178 4730`

Comment: nc: connect to 51.15.234.178 port 4730 (tcp) failed: Connection refusedd.scaleway.com [51.15.234.178] 4730 (?) : Connection refused

Maybe the port isn't open after all, even though my netstat shows it is:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4730          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4730          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3857/gearmand 

This is what netstat -plunt gives me

Comment: either gearmand is running with improper `--listen` argument or there is some network filtering between gearman- and clients/workers-hosts.

Comment: What should be the --listen argument? I've set none.

nmap shows me only port 22 is open and the other 999 are closed. I've tried opening with iptables etc. But can't seem to get it open on my Scaleway server.

Comment: `--listen` is optionally. If you don't use it, network filtering leads to the issue. Both `nc` and `nmap` says the same: you can't connect to 4730

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to get the port opened. If it doesn't work I'll ask here agin :)

Comment: I've tried SSH tunneling with `/usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -NL 4731:localhost:4731 51.15.232.176` however with this I also get the same message of no connection

Comment: lucky you 4730 on 51.15.232.176 is closed: `$ nc -v -w2 51.15.232.176 4730
nc: connect to 51.15.232.176 port 4730 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`. Take care about information you post publicly!. You should open 4730 only for particular hosts or network.

Comment: I understand, that's why I made a test server just to get it going. There wasn't anything vital in there :) I've figured out how to get it going in the end. so I'm all set!